# jquery read text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, get, readfile

i have a problem.
i want read a txt file by jquery and process my data.
but there are a few problem.
maybe you can help me.
"can.txt" is my text file.

can.txt
...

```
clicked dot,{"x":561.7921,"y":518.5893},"time":"2016-03-03 10:05:27.043"
clicked dot,{"x":119.5832,"y":116.8342},"time":"2016-03-03 10:05:27.230"
clicked dot,{"x":561.7921,"y":518.5893},"time":"2016-03-03 10:05:27.500" 
clicked dot,{"x":329.0134,"y":244.9823},"time":"2016-03-03 10:05:28.111"
```

... etc. continue it.There are multiple data on one line
there are avarage 50 data in a second 
sometimes data to be negative or zero.
there are avarage 50 data in a second 
i want read my file real time and take x and y data.

my jquery code

```
    <script>
var tarih=new Date();
var st = tarih.getHours();
var dk = tarih.getMinutes();
var sn = tarih.getSeconds();
var search = st+":"+dk+":"+sn;
var place=0;
$.get('can.txt', function(data) {    
var lines = data.split("\n\g");

$.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
place = elem.indexOf(search,place);
place2= elem.lastIndexOf(search);
if(place != -1) 
{
   getX=elem.substring(place-500,place2);//i get all value in a second
  //in here i must find and get x and y value in getX
  //how can i get these values easyly?
  //if i run code half hours , the can.txt file size is avarege 10-15 mb.
  // i wanted use regex but it doesn't work :/ 
  if (getX.match(/^x":[0-9]$/))
  $('#div').append('<div>' getX+'</div>');  
}    
});
});
setTimeout(bak(),1000);
</script>

<div id="div"> </div>
```

i use php and actionscript 3.0 this problem but both of them run slow.
maybe it is my fault.anyway
i use $.get function in jquery but you know another function faster than this ($.post,$.ajax, etc.) that you say me who be so happy.
thanks a lot everyone that read my problem. i wait your opinion and solition.

Comment: Do you need to read the file with jquery or can you process the file with just php?

Comment: I'd expect that the iterator (`each`) will supply individual text lines. Assuming that there is a single record in each line and that each line contains coordinate pairs, you could extract a coordinate pair as follows: `$('#div').append(elem.replace(/^.*"x":(-?[0-9.]+).*?"y":(-?[0-9.]+).*$/, "<div><span>$1</span><span>$2</span></div>")';`. That would be the sole content of your iterator callback function.The `$.get` call is but syntactic sugar for `$.ajax`, as is `$.post` which uses a different mechanism to wrap up url parameters. Regex live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gV8iG9/1).